# Check if string contain only letters

Tags: c++

I have a trouble with a search through a string, if I enter a word with only letters, it's work as needs, I though, the code works, but when I add a number in work, the code work also, the question that, is possible to accept only if my var contains only letters, and if it will find a number or symbol, to go at begining of code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    label:
    string var1 = "";
cout << "Enter a word: ";
cin >> var1;
    for (int i = 0; i < var1.size (); i++)
    {
        int uppercaseCHar = toupper (var1[i]);
        if (uppercaseCHar < 'A' || uppercaseCHar > 'Z')
        {
            goto endloop;
            cout << endl;

        } else
            goto label;
            cout << endl;

       }
     endloop:
     cout << "Yout word contains only letters";

    }
```

```
Output: 
Enter a word: work
Enter a word: wro1
Enter a word: 123
Yout word contains only letters
```

Comment: your `if` condition is almost certainly backwards. But using gotos like that is pretty uncommon style, too.

Comment: Don't use `goto endloop;`. Use `break;` instead

Comment: I change to break, and I change && instead of ||, but now I got only False
  if (uppercaseCHar < 'A' && uppercaseCHar > 'Z')
  {
   
   cout << "True\n";
   break;

  } else
      cout << "False\n";
      break;
  
   
       }

Comment: and I see I got this warning on the if line: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions. what that means?

Comment: You should be using `isalpha` for this, and if constructed properly, one of the `std::find` family members and the begin/end iterators of your word. It would make your code *considerably* more compact.

Comment: That means one value in the comparison is signed (can be positive and negative) and the other is unsigned (positive only). This can be trouble if one of the values is impossible to reach (negative for example, large enough to be unreachable by the signed number). In this case (`for (int i = 0; i < var1.size (); i++)`), `int` is signed and the result of `var1.size ()` is not.

Comment: @Cartoon27 `bool isallLetters = std::all_of(var1.begin(), var1.end(), ::isalpha);` -- A one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses [std::all_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    bool isAllLetters = false;
    do 
    {
        std::string var1;
        std::cout << "Enter a word: ";
        std::cin >> var1;

        // check if all characters are letters
        isAllLetters = std::all_of(var1.begin(), var1.end(), [](char ch) 
                                  { return std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch));});

        if ( isAllLetters )
           std::cout << "Your word contains only letters\n";
        else
           std::cout << "Your word contains stuff other than letters\n"
    } while ( !isAllLetters );
}
```

Comment: Note that this potentially invokes undefined behaviour as the values passed to `isalpha` should be casted to `unsigned char` to avoid issues with those that aren't representable, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha

Comment: I adjusted the answer to do the cast to `unsigned char`.

Comment: You can directly take `unsigned char ch` for conciseness.

Answer (score 2):

Simple and efficient (C++17):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string_view>

bool all_of_alpha(std::string_view s)
{
  return std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), [](unsigned char c) { return std::isalpha(c); });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `goto` as it will complicate debugging code in larger program  , here's another way :

```
int main()
{
    while (true) {
        bool flag = false;  // to check for numeric entry

        string var1; // not req to initialize
        cout << "Enter a word (press exit to end): ";
        cin >> var1;

        for (int i = 0; i < var1.size(); i++)
        {
            int uppercaseCHar = toupper(var1[i]);
            if (!std::isalpha(uppercaseCHar))
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (var1.compare("exit") == 0) break;

        if (flag) {
            cout << "Your word contains number";
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
       {
            cout << "Your word contains only alphabets";
            cout << endl;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: uhm, it's more complicated than I expect, but it works, need a time to understand your version, line by line, thx

Comment: `if (uppercaseCHar < 'A' || uppercaseCHar > 'Z')` seems to be not portable

Comment: The outer while loop is to allow multiple entries of words. You can remove it if it is just for a single word check.

Comment: @user3365922: It is portable, just comverts a char to its ASCII

Comment: @seccpur https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58003555/string-repetition-replaced-by-hyphen-c#comment102412380_58003555

Comment: @seccpur it is exceptionally rare these days, but not all computers use ASCII. The famous example is IBM mainframes using EBCDIC, an encoding based on old punch cards and as a result looks like it was laid out by a lunatic. Made a lot of sense back in the 1960s, though.

Comment: @seccpur more to the point, you're assuming ascii, and can *probably* get away with it. Reality is it hedged to whatever platform you're building this on. The standard does not require continuity with no breaks between `A..Z` ; it only mandates that for *digits* (e.g `0..9`). That range check is therefore not portable, but will most likely work on the platforms the OP and their prof run this on regardless.

Comment: @seccpur, yes, I understand what while do, just I use before "goto", will you explain, why I should not use it?

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thanks for the input. I try to change that line for portablility.

Comment: @Cartoon27: Added a bit of an explaination.

Comment: @seccpur the only way to change that to portable is to eliminate the literal range in the first place. Eliminating the range check, the toupper, and just using `std::isalpha` is the most direct approach

Comment: @seccpur, ok, I got it

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to offer a more modern idiomatic version and *assuming you only care about detecting alphabetic characters in the ASCII character set*.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string a = "abcdefgh";
    std::string b = "abcd3fgh";
    std::string c = "abcdefg0";

    auto is_alpha = [](unsigned char c){ return std::isalpha(c); };

    bool aContainsAlphas = std::all_of(a.begin(), a.end(), is_alpha);
    bool bContainsAlphas = std::all_of(b.begin(), b.end(), is_alpha);
    bool cContainsAlphas = std::all_of(c.begin(), c.end(), is_alpha);

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "A: " << aContainsAlphas << '\n';    // true
    std::cout << "B: " << bContainsAlphas << '\n';    // false
    std::cout << "C: " << cContainsAlphas << '\n';    // false
}
```

This defines a lambda which is passed as an argument to `std::all_of`, which uses it to test each character:

```cpp
auto is_alpha = [](unsigned char c){ return std::isalpha(c); };
```

This invokes `is_alpha` on each element between `a.begin()` and `a.end()`. If the end is reached without any mismatch for `is_alpha`, then `true` is returned.

```cpp
bool aContainsAlphas = std::all_of(a.begin(), a.end(), is_alpha) != a.end();
```

Comment: Your solution does not require ASCII.  (Thus portable)

Comment: Yes, however it obviously only works on the ASCII alphabet, e.g. `á` will invalidate the check. And I assume it will only work on UTF-8 Unicode. Not sure about UTF-16 or 32.

Comment: It *will* work with non-ASCII provided proper locale support, actually.  But that's not important :)

Comment: Didn't know that, nice to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expressions which will simplify the code further.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;


int main () {

    regex reg_obj("^[A-Z]+$");     
    string var;
    start_label:
        cout << "Enter a word: ";
        getline(cin, var);
        if(regex_match(var, reg_obj))
            goto endlabel;
        else goto start_label;
    endlabel:
        cout << "your word contains only letters\n";

return 0;
```

};